# How to declare RAM variable as volatile in STM8 assembly language

Tags: assembly, volatile, stm8

I want to know how i can declare any RAM variable as volatile in STM8 assembly language. I have one variable, which is shared between ISR and main function. It is causing issue during updates, when the software is in free run mode.

Can anyone tell me that how to declare any variable as volatile in STM8 assembly.

Comment: Volatile and non-volatile use the same memory -- there is no difference.  The processor only sees machine code instructions.  It only sees memory through those instructions -- it does not see data declarations.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know how I can declare any ... variable as `volatile` in ... assembly language.

In C, the `volatile` keyword tells the compiler not to leave out certain assembly instructions when translating C to assembly language.

When you write a program in assembly language, it makes no sense to declare something as `volatile`: Either your (hand-written) code contains certain assembly instructions or it does not contain them.

Comment: if this is the case, then why shared variable updates are not working in assembly language ?

Comment: @HiteshKumarTiwari I can't tell without seeing your code.  That said, make sure the variable is aligned and not larger than your machine's word size.